# print specific dom window using any of the language php,javascript

Tags: php, printing

In my application I have created many graphs using php and dom and I have one print button associated with each graph,so on click of each print button i need to print associated graph.how to achieve it.any suggestion???

Answer (score 1):

Generate various [print stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) that set `display: none` on different bits of the page and include a [stylesheet switcher](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) along with a call to `window.print()` for each one.